# MySQL не использует индексы в запросе

Tags: mysql, sql, index

Запрос `SELECT * FROM surv_tokens WHERE token=1111111111;`

Индекс на `token` создан

В `token` уникальное числовое целое значение всегда без `NA`

В `surv_tokens` более 10 млн записей

ответ explain:

```
id, select_type, table,             type, possible_keys,         key,  key_len, ref,  rows,     Extra
1,  SIMPLE,      surv_tokens_27648, ALL,  idx_surv_tokens_token, NULL, NULL,    NULL, 10316268, "Using where"
key= null
possible_keys
```

видит, но не использует.

Почему?

key_buffer_size = 268435456
Размер таблицы 2Гб
index length таблицы 975 Мб

Пробовал уникальный и не уникальный индекс. И не надо говорить, что движок базы данных считает использования индекса неэффективным. Запрос выполняется 2 секунды, количество запросов иногда десятки в секунду. Использование индекса тут будет чертовски эффективным.

Comment: Какой код создания индекса? Был ли завершен процесс создания индекса перед запросом?

Comment: Это нормально, что в плане имя таблицы отличается?

Comment: @RomanKonoval наверно нет, но по плану в таблице 10 млн записей, но в плане `key=NULL`. Есть подозрение, что индекс для такой большой таблицы просто не успел построиться перед запросом, либо сам индекс некорректный

Comment: >>Какой код создания индекса? Был ли завершен процесс создания индекса перед запросом? Индекс создавался средствами MySQL Workbench, код заметить не успел. Да, процесс полностью завершен, прошло уже несколько недель.

Comment: >> Это нормально, что в плане имя таблицы отличается?  Да, нормально, название писал руками, таблиц surv_tokens с различными номерами в базе много, и для всех из них ключ не используется при таких запросах. Ответ expain просто скопировал из конкретной таблицы, поэтому он с номером.

Comment: >> @RomanKonoval наверно нет, но по плану в таблице 10 млн записей, но в плане key=NULL. Есть подозрение, что индекс для такой большой таблицы просто не успел построиться перед запросом, либо сам индекс некорректный. Индексы пересоздал много раз, его создание давно завершено, это видно по загрузке процессора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оказался очень прост.
Вместо

```
SELECT * FROM surv_tokens WHERE token=1111111111;
```

нужен запрос

```
SELECT * FROM surv_tokens WHERE token="1111111111";
```

тогда ключ используется.